# How get Data from a textbox and add it to dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, html-table

I am trying to be able to get the information from the text ex:"Name,Number,etc"; and add that information to my data Table, but I cannot figure out how to get that part working. I also have the jsfiddle attached which works properly. (https://jsfiddle.net/gon3j0uv/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var t = $('#example').DataTable();
  var counter = 1;

  $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
    t.row.add([
      counter + '.1',
      counter + '.2',
      counter + '.3',
      counter + '.4',
      counter + '.5'
    ]).draw(false);

    counter++;
  });

  // Automatically add a first row of data
  $('#addRow').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<button id="addRow">
  addrow
</button>
</br>
</br>
</br>

First name:
<input type="text" name="FirstName">
<br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

```
    counter++;
} );

// Automatically add a first row of data
$('#addRow').click();
```

} );

[jsFiddle](http://%3Cscript%20async%20src=%22//jsfiddle.net/gon3j0uv/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

Comment: To quote the tag snippet, "(Note that Java is not to be confused with JavaScript)".

Comment: You want to insert the text inputed in "First name" into a table cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the value in the input text, I edited your fiddle here is the link [Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ingemi/gon3j0uv/1/)

You have to get the value of the input like this:

```
var inputText = $("input[name='FirstName']").val()
```

If you want text for all columns, you should have diferent input for each column. I hope it helps